# Liferay Login Hook, error pop up

Tags: authentication, liferay, jsp-tags, liferay-hook

I need to show the errors in login hook of liferay in popup, but the sentence is only a line of code, so I don't know how implement the popup.
the key line is the next:

```
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= NoSuchUserException.class %>" message="This message is editable" />
```

This error is to showed in a label but I didn't need this.

like this example::
http://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/bootstrap-modal.png

Comment: So you are trying to modify the standard login.jsp via a hook and you want to show the error message when user was not found. By popup you mean the standard popup, that is sometimes used to show the login portlet or something else?

Comment: yes, of course, I use a login hook but my goal is to show the error login, everything, in popup, like modal window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to show errors in dialog box,I suppose you are using

```
SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "error");
```

to send error from action phase.You can check SeesionErrors for 'error' attribute and display your message in dialog box:

```
       <% if(!SessionErrors.isEmpty(renderRequest))
    {
        String error=LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "error");
        %>
    <aui:script>
  YUI().ready(function(A) {
    YUI().use('aui-base','liferay-util-window', function(A) {
        Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow({
            title : 'Error',
            dialog: {   
                bodyContent: '<%=error%>',
                destroyOnHide: true,
                cache: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 300,
                width: 300
                     }
                        })
                            });
                               });
    </aui:script>
    <%} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have look at the Alloy Documentation
http://alloyui.com/examples/tooltip/

As Shivam suggested, you can use a scriplet to get the message.